# Dumping values of a sensor in file at regular time interval

Tags: java, android, android-sensors

I am trying to make a android app which collects the data from the sensors. I used the sensor event listener to get the values of the sensor and it gives me value every time the reading of the sensor changes. What I want is that I want to average out those values for a particular time interval and then I want to dump that averaged value in the output.csv file.
what I can use to average out the value for some regular time interval in java/android.

Comment: Maybe, try putting the values into a database each time you get a new update from the sensors and then run a periodical job in background to calculate the average, or maybe, just trigger a calculation in background once a certain time / threshold is reached...

Comment: You can use [Evernote Job](https://github.com/evernote/android-job) if you want to schedule a Job